# Ruby on Rails - I can't send a form - 400 Bad Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying send a form in Ruby on Rails, but when try send I get the following error:

```
Started POST "/newsletters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-02 14:26:33 -0300
Processing by NewslettersController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓"}
[1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36m (0.4ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 400 Bad Request in 14ms (Views: 0.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

The form has just one field (email) and I already validate it in my model. What's going on? Why 400 Bad Request? Anyone con help me?

newsletter_mailer.rb

```
class NewsletterMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "no-reply@facens.br"

  def create(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: "felipe.marcon@atua.ag", subject: "Contato Através do Site")
  end
end
```

newsletters_controller.rb

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @newsletter = Newsletter.new(params[:newsletters])
    if @newsletter.save
      NewsletterMailer.delay_for(1.seconds, retry: true).create(@newsletter)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end
end
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(Newsletter.new, remote: true, html: { multipart: true }, html: {class:"fc_liga__footer--form clearfix"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="input_group">
    <input type="text" id="contact[email]" placeholder="Digite o seu e-mail">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn_orange"><%= svg "send_newsletter" %></button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Have you tried to make this service call in a REST client?  From the contents of your question, I'm not entirely sure the tags `jquery` and especially `html` are applicable.  If you use a REST client to make this request, and you get the same error, that would suggest it is a backend issue, not a frontend issue.

Comment: @Taplar How can I do this? Call in a REST client?

Comment: For your browser of choice, firefox or chrome, check their app store.  There are free add-ons offered that provide this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your parameters don't include `:newsletters`, see?

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓"}
```

So, `@newsletter.save` is `false` and you get a `400` error, just as you specified:

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @newsletter = Newsletter.new(params[:newsletters])
    if @newsletter.save
      NewsletterMailer.delay_for(1.seconds, retry: true).create(@newsletter)
      render nothing: true, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 400
    end
  end
end
```

You don't have `params[:newsletters]` because your form is malformed:

```
<%= form_for(Newsletter.new, remote: true, html: { multipart: true }, html: {class:"fc_liga__footer--form clearfix"}) do |f| %>
  <div class="input_group">
    <input type="text" id="contact[email]" placeholder="Digite o seu e-mail">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn_orange"><%= svg "send_newsletter" %></button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You shouldn't manually create the input, you should use an input helper instead.

Comment: Now I'm using input helper, but the 400 Bad Request still presenting problems.

`Started POST "/newsletters" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-05-02 15:33:26 -0300
Processing by NewslettersController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "newsletter"=>{"email"=>"felipeemarcon@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Enviar"}
   (7.8ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 400 Bad Request in 12ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 8.2ms)`

Comment: Your params includes `:newsletter`, not `:newsletters` as specified here: `@newsletter = Newsletter.new(params[:newsletters])`.